# React-admin Gantt chart?

Tags: react-admin, gantt-chart

Has anyone tried to implement a Gantt chart with react-admin?

We're attempting to do it with IBM's Gantt chart - https://github.com/IBM/gantt-chart

It's not ideal because IBM's Gantt chart basically is self sufficient and so it doesn't necessarily integrate great with react-admin. They have a react component that helps but had to deal with issues like it duplicating itself and loading way more data than will show up just to make filters work correct.

Anyway, just wondering if anyone else has any experience to share with building a Gantt chart in react-admin.

Thanks